# Cannot get Boost to build correctly

Tags: c++, boost, installation

I needed to built Boost.Python to work for version 3.2 and I keep running into problems. I followed the instructions in the Getting Started Guide — both the [general instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) and those specifically [about Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/python/doc/building.html) — and I can't get it to work.

Here's the program I'm trying to run and the link error I'm getting:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test) { }
int main() { return 0; }
```

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc100-mt-1_48.lib'

Indeed, there is no such file, but there is a '*libboost*_python-vc100-mt-1_48.lib' file. (Unsurprisingly, if I try to change its name, it'll give another link error.)

The command I used to install the libraries was:

```
C:\...\boost_1_48_0> b2 --build-dir=C:\Boost toolset=msvc --build-type=complete install
```

And the content of my 'user-config.jam' file in my home directory was:

```
using python : 3.2 : C:/Programming/PythonX86/Python32 ;
```

Comment: @Mark That's a typo while I wrote this question. The command wouldn't have worked if I specified a compiler that did not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're only building the static boost_python library binary.  Have you tried the following command line options for b2?

```
link=shared runtime-link=shared
```

Also, if linking to a static library is acceptable for your needs, adding BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB to your preprocessor definitions should do the trick...

Comment: Thanks! The macro did the trick. I'll use the static libraries for now, until I'm in the mood again to try and get the dynamic libraries working.